# How to remove definitions from top level (OCaml)

Tags: ocaml

Is there any way to remove all definitions from the OCaml top level with a directive or something similar?

At the moment I just type the following commands in the terminal, but I was wondering if there's anything better.

```
# #quit;;
$ ocaml
```

Comment: why do you want to remove all definitions ?

Comment: How could another solution be better than that?

Comment: @MichaelGrunewald It's mostly for students I'm helping. I feel like they won't want to type this much, and so I was hoping there would be a #amazing directive or similar solution that would make it better than this. I know it's very little, but 2 > 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing documented in the [list of toplevel directives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html) that does this. I think your current solution is quite elegant and effective :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no (as has been written). But usability can be improved:

I suggest Ctrl+d to replace #quit;;

Then there is a cursor-up key to recall the last command.

Side note:

not using a readline wrapper like rlwrap? 
For example with `alias ocamli="rlwrap ocaml"`

:-)